# Shelve - Can't delete entry

Tags: python, shelve

Hi this is my shelve entry structure

```
{
    'Birds' : {
        'BlueOnes': ["detailsAboutBlueBird"], 
        'RedOnes' : ["detailsAboutRedBirds"]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove only `BlueOnes`

Below is the code I'm using

```
s = shelve.open('birds.db')
del s['Birds']['BlueOnes']
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong o.o?

Comment: `s['birds']` resolves to an ordinary Python dict; there's no way for `shelve` to notice the change you made to it.  You either need to make an explicit change to the top-level object (`s['birds'] = s['birds']` should do it), or specify `writeback=True` in your call to `shelve.open()` so that it writes back *every* item you ever retrieved, in case you modified it (this has performance implications).

Answer (score 0):

In *`shelve`* if you want to detect the changes automatically use the `writeback` flag which remember all the objects that are retrieved from the database using an in-memory cache if the flag is set True such that when we close the shelf all the objects are written back to the database.

```
s = shelve.open('birds.db', writeback=True)
```

Comment: Yes, it is mentioned in the answer description that all the objects are written back to the database once you close the connection